# How to embed toleo job search page in my aspx page

Tags: iframe

I want to try to embed toleo job search page in my aspx page. i want to use iframe.

I am using

```
http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH10/ats/careers/jobSearch.jsp?org=TILLCLOT&cws=39
```

How to do that

I tried

```
<iframe> http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH10/ats/careers/jobSearch.jsp?org=TILLCLOT&cws=39 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<iframe src="http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH10/ats/careers/jobSearch.jsp?org=TILLCLOT&cws=39"></iframe>
```

May I also suggest you visit [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) so that you can learn more about HTML, ASP.NET and much more.

Comment: Is it possible to do the other way around ? I want to embed my application widget in Taleo web page, I don't know if there is a way to embed the iframe there. I appreciate any kind of help, thanks !